# Search if data exists in Database and make an action

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database with some data.i would like to check every time i press a button if my link is already in the database.If it exists i will show a toast,else i will write it in the db.

```
    public boolean Exists(String link) {
           Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select 1 from fav where link="+link, 
                new String[] {link });
           boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
           cursor.close();
           return exists;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **:** in the URL is confusing sqlite. You could escape it by surrounding the URL with single quotes.

your `Exists(String link)` function should be as below

```
 public boolean Exists(String link) {
           Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select 1 from fav where link='"+link+"'",new String[] {});
           boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
           cursor.close();
           return exists;
        }
```

Comment: i posted the error of your method in my question (as logcat2) :)

Comment: i have updated the answer please check it. The reason for the error is `new String[] {link}` because we are passing a argument to bind with query but our query doesn't have any parameters. Change that to `new String[] {}`